# Find the computational complexity of the following 'for' loop

Tags: big-o, complexity-theory, time-complexity

What is the complexity of the following `for` loop?

```
n = 0;
for (i = 1; i <= N; i++)
{    
    s(i) = sum of the first i coordinates of a
           fixed vector (of dimension N);

    % suppose r(i) (for all i) is already computed
    if (r(i) s(i) > r(n) s(n))
        n = i;  
}
```

Comment: What does `r(i) s(i)` mean?  Multiplication of `r(i)` and `s(i)`?

Comment: yes, it is the multiplication.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The worst case complexity of your loop is o(N²).

The loop is executed N times. Every iteration has another dependency to N, because:

```
s(i) = sum of the first i coordinates of a fixed vector (of dimension N);
```

I can't see any dependecy of N here, so in http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation it's just constant:

```
% suppose r(i) (for all i) is already computed
if (r(i) s(i) > r(n) s(n))
    n = i;
```

Comment: Yes but we are looking at infinite high numbers using the big o notation. So infinity-1, infinity-2 is still within o(n) afaik. At least i am quite sure it's higher than log(n).

Comment: Yes, definately N² (source web.mit.edu/16.070/www/lecture/big_o.pdf): "In a common special case where the stopping condition of the inner loop is J<N instead
of J<M (i.e., the inner loop also executes N times), the total complexity for the two loops
is O(N2)."

Comment: @Journeycorner: strictly speaking, the condition reduces the cost of the loop by a factor of approximately two, but as usual the constant factor is ignored when discussing complexity.  That's why it's still quadratic.

Comment: @Rufflewind: I think that the exact answer is O(N(N+1)/2) since we have 1+2+...i+...+N sums.  Is it right ? or we should also take the  'if' condition into consideration?

Comment: @mat: afaik the big o notation is only about the "class" of the grow, e.g. n pot n > n² > n log n > n > log n. So you could say the above example is O(n²). See http://web.mit.edu/16.070/www/lecture/big_o.pdf

Comment: @mat: In big-O notation you only care about the leading term, and ignore any constant coefficients.